# How do you convert FString into Char* ? UE4

Tags: game-engine

```
    const char* bufmessage = PlayerLocation;
    int sendOK = sendto(out, bufmessage, strlen(bufmessage), 0, (sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server));
```

no suitable conversion for FString to const char*

Answer (score 3):

A 1 line solution to convert from some FString to char* would be this:

```
// Assuming you have some FString myFString created e.g., with TEXT("Some FString")
char* result = TCHAR_TO_ANSI(*myFString);
```

Note: As the comments point out, this assumes the FString will not go out of scope.

Comment: Very dangerous to store the return value in a local variable, the converted value is only for temporal use. Please refer to the comment in the answer of `Steve Robb`: https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/563141/tchar-to-ansi-limitation-to-128-characters.html

Comment: @ALittleDiff Yes, I agree, my response is meant to answer "how to convert FString into char*", so it assumes that the FString exists and will not go out of scope. I edited the answer a bit to be a bit more clear, but it is purely answering the original question.